# Get Name of Selected ListBoxItem on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF/C#, and I'm trying to create a simple sql query application to get used to it.  I have a listbox and a corresponding button in my XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="dbTables" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBoxItem>Log</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>DownloadRequest</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>EmailRequest</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <!-- View report button -->
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="125" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click">View</Button>
```

and the corresponding C# function:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String curItem = dbTables.SelectedValue.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("CurItem = " + curItem);
        Results resultsPage = new Results(curItem);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(resultsPage);

    }
```

However, when it outputs the CurItem it has this value:

`CurItem = System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: Log`

Which then throws an exception when I try to run a SQL Query.  I'm trying to get it to just be
`CurItem = Log`

I've tried several different ways but I can't seem to just get the name of the selected value without the object definition attached.

Comment: did you tried by setting this <ListBoxItem Value="Log">Log</ListBoxItem>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Selected Value is a ListBoxItem, so you can cast the value to ListBoxItem, and then use the Content property:

```
ListBoxItem selItem = (ListBoxItem)dbTables.SelectedValue;

        Console.WriteLine(selItem.Content);
```

Comment: Do you know why `SelectedValue` ends up being a `ListBoxItem` in this simple case? I mean, we also have `SelectedItem` and all that.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen:  see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedItem` returns the currently selected item in the list box.  Since you're populating your list box with `ListBoxItem`s, that's what it will return.  (Note, by the way, that your list box automatically generates `ListBoxItem` containers for its items - if you look in the visual tree, you'll find that this `ListBox` contains `ListBoxItem`s, each of which contains a `ListBoxItem`.  `SelectedItem` contains the content of the generated `ListBoxItem`, which is to say the `ListBoxItem` you're creating in markup.)

`SelectedValue` returns the value of the property of `SelectedItem` that is specified by `ListBox.SelectedValuePath`.  If no `SelectedValuePath` is given, it returns `SelectedItem`, so if you don't know about `SelectedValuePath`, it seems like the two are the same thing.  But if you populate your list with, say, `Person` objects, and set `SelectedValuePath` to `"Name"`, the `SelectedValue` will contain the selected person's name, not a reference to the `Person` object.

So in your example, you can make `SelectedValue` return the string by setting `SelectedValuePath` to `"Content"`, which is the property of the `ListBoxItem` that contains the strings you're using.

You can do it another way by not explicitly creating `ListBoxItem`s and just populating the `ListBox` with strings.  You have to declare a namespace referencing `mscorlib` to do this, so that you can represent string objects in XAML, but once you do, the result's simple:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <DockPanel>  
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" x:Name="test" SelectedValuePath="Length">
      <sys:String>Log</sys:String>
      <sys:String>DownloadRequest</sys:String>
      <sys:String>EmailRequest</sys:String>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Text="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=SelectedItem}"/>    
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Text="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=SelectedValue}"/>    
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Whoa, very nice. I take this is still going to create ListBoxItem instances, right? So there's some type checking going on so that you can use other objects as well, and non-ListBoxItems get wrapped in an item automatically?

Comment: Yes.  All items controls wrap their items in a container - that's what `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator` does.  If you ever need items to have attached properties (e.g. if the items template is a `Grid` and you want to set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`), you'll need to set them with `ItemContainerStyle` instead of putting them in the `ItemTemplate`, which is the primary reason you need to know this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String curItem = (dbTables.SelectedValue as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```